# Why this simple way to generate random integers work

Tags: random

```
var r = 12345

func rand() int {
    r = r*1103515245 + 12345
    return r & 0x7fffffff
}
```

This go function generate random numbers but I do not why it works (I did not evaluate how well it works.. just eyeballing the results). Can someone explain please? Thanks

you could see it here in action: https://go.dev/play/p/ji4-avVV1Mn

I am aware this may not be cryptographically safe.

Comment: from a glance it looks like it's just using integer overflows to make a deterministic "random" number generator. In otherwords, you can think of the numbers there like the seed to your RNG. However, this ordering is currently hard-coded, and will simply return the same numbers every time in order of invocation. I wouldn't use this for anything aside from maybe a cheap visual effect, the order is predictable and thus exploitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recurrence relationship can be written as `r <- (a * r + c) % m`, since `r & 0x7fffffff` is equivalent to `r % (0x7fffffff + 1)` (where `%` denotes the modulo operation). This is the definition a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). Your particular implementation has `a = 1103515245`, `c = 12345`, and `m = 2**31`.
Entries on lines 4 and 5 of the [Parameters in common use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) table on the LCG Wikipedia page show that those choices of `a`, `c`, and `m` are known and yield a full cycle generator, i.e., one which achieves the maximum possible period before outcomes start repeating.

Achieving full cycle does *not* make this a good generator. My very first [journal publication](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167637786900921) back in the mid 1980's showed that if you draw samples from a pool of size `m`, the logic of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says that by the time you've seen `3 * sqrt(m)` values at least one duplicate should have occurred with probability `p > 0.99`. For `m = 2**31` this means there should be one or more duplicate values by the time you've seen slightly more than 139,000 values from your generator. This gives us a simple statistical test—failure to generate any duplicates within a sample of that size fails the hypothesis that the samples are independent at an α = 0.01 level. Being full cycle means that you're guaranteed to not see any duplicates until you've generated all 2**31 possible values, and hence you will always fail this birthday test with a full cycle generator which reports its full state. This is one of several statistical tests that LCGs systematically fail.

To summarize, this is a known linear congruential generator, but I wouldn't recommend using it for any serious work. Much better alternatives for pseudo-random number generation are readily available these days.